# How to plot horizontally with gghalves::geom_half_boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

is it possible to stick with `facet_wrap` and avoid `coord_flip`?
The issue seems to be that the argument `side` in `geom_half_violin` and `geom_half_boxplot` only takes `"r"` or `"l"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gghalves)

as_tibble(iris) %>%
  pivot_longer(!Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Measure, Value)) +
  geom_half_violin(side = "l") +
  geom_half_boxplot(side = "r", outlier.shape = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

[image]

```r
as_tibble(iris) %>%
  pivot_longer(!Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Measure, Value)) +
  geom_half_violin(side = "r") +
  geom_half_boxplot(side = "l", outlier.shape = NA) +
  facet_grid(Species ~ .) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

```r
as_tibble(iris) %>%
  pivot_longer(!Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Value, Measure)) +
  geom_half_violin(side = "l") +
  geom_half_boxplot(side = "r", outlier.shape = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
#> Warning: position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
#> position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
#> Error in data.frame(x = data$x, xend = data$x, y = c(data$upper, data$lower), : Argumente implizieren unterschiedliche Anzahl Zeilen: 0, 2, 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is there a workaround for that limitation?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `facet_grid`?

Comment: Because in my real data I use ```ggh4x::facet_nested_wrap```, and ```ggh4x::facet_nested_grid``` does not exist.

Comment: `facet_nested()` is the grid-layout variant of `facet_nested_wrap()`.

Comment: @teunbrand ```facet_nested()``` cannot use ```strip.position = "right"```. How can I get the facet label to the right side with ```facet_nested```?

Comment: The same way you would with `facet_grid()`, namely by using `switch = "y"` (not tested).

Comment: I will test that and report :)

Comment: Unfortunately, ```switch = "y"``` does not work. The facet labels are still on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in line with what you are looking for? This specifies that strip.position would be on "top" after the coordflip. I think you'd still need the coord flip if you wanted the 'raincloud' type look.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghalves)
library(ggh4x)

as_tibble(iris) %>%
    pivot_longer(!Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Measure, y=Value)) +
    geom_half_violin(side = "r") +
    geom_half_boxplot(side = "l", outlier.shape = NA) +
    facet_nested_wrap(vars(Species), strip.position = c("top")) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Changing strip.position should move their positions around for left, right, top, and bottom:

```
as_tibble(iris) %>%
    pivot_longer(!Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Measure, y=Value)) +
    geom_half_violin(side = "r") +
    geom_half_boxplot(side = "l", outlier.shape = NA) +
    facet_nested_wrap(vars(Species), strip.position = c("right")) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]